# JavaScript Pass variable event to event listener

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, addeventlistener, mouseclick-event

I'm working on a canvas paint project and I'm trying to change the event type of an event listener. For example, a user selects (i) Click or (ii) Mouseover. Then "Click" or "Mouseover" are passed as parameters to the event listener. Been scratching my head on it for a day or so. Not sure if the event is immutable. Anyway thought I'd post it. Also, I'm using range as the input (with values of 0 and 1). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<input type="range" id="state" name="state" min="0" max="1" value="0" onchange="changestate();">
```

```
$state = "mousemove";  // Global Variable

function changestate(){
x = document.getElementByID("state").value;

if(x == 1){
      $state = "mousemove";
      } else {
             $state = "click";
}

canvas.addEventListener($state, function (evt) {
      //code
}, false);
```

Comment: The event object is created by the browser, and the type of the event is always something an event handler can check. Also, understand that adding an event handler does not remove previously-added event handlers (which may be OK for your purposes).

Comment: The event listener won't change what its listening for once its started so whatever its initial value is (`mouseover`)

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I made some edits. Also, thank you for the information about the event listener not changing. Will see if I can come up with a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the following got me what I was looking for. Thank you all for your help.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {
    var mousestate = document.getElementById("state").value;
    if(mousestate == 0){
                // code
                }
    } else {
         canvas.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
                //code
             }, false);
           }

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do this with two different event listener's, but you can just pass the same function into them and then check with that function whether or not to run code for the `mouseover` event or `click`

**JS**

```
$state = "mousemove";  // Global Variable

function changestate() {
    x = document.getElementById("state").value;
  if (x == 1) {
    $state = "mousemove";
  } else {
    $state = "click";
  }
}
 
function doSomething(evt) {
  if ($state == 0) {
    // put all the code here for click event
  } else if ($state == 1) {
    // put all the code here for mouseover event
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false)
window.addEventListener('mouseover', doSomething, false)
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you Ben!! Will give that a try and revert back.

Comment: @kjregan120 no worries, if this works for you can you accept it as answered thanks :)

Comment: Other than using a global variable, you could store the state in the DOM, as an attribute or as a class.